# My composer give me mkdir() permission denied exception

Tags: laravel

I have run

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

this command in htdocs cmd. It worked several times. But now its giving me mkdir() permission denied Error. Why is that??

It should have created a file named Project_mig! I wonder what went wrong. :(

[image]

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run this command in your Windows installation folder which you don't have permission to write.

You can see this from the command line

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>
```

The solution would be `cd` to other folder or drive that you have permission to write (ex: D Drive) and run the command again.

Example:

```
D:

cd D:/Projects // Might be different based on your folder structure

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Because you said the same command works on Git Bash. That is because Git Bash default folder is `~` which points to current user folder in your system. Because it is your own user folder, you can do anything there including write. That's why your script works fine using Git Bash.

Comment: But the same command i am running by GIT Bash & its working fine !

Comment: Git bash default folder is your current user folder where you have permission to do everything

Answer (score 2):

First go to the folder where you want to create the project.
Then : [do as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3IZX.png)
After that execute "composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog" code.

Answer (score -1):

First of all mkdir() i.e. making new folder/directory permissions error is because of Lack of permissions at the time of performing the same command

you can create your project in different directory

Comment: Running with administrator will cause even more problems in coding later on